# How high is "very high reputation score" in user deletion process?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

In [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) you can find in the description about rep loss because "user removed":

> This removal occurs whenever a user is deleted, unless that user had a very high reputation score.

Which is considered "high reputation score"? From what reputation a user removed will not remove the rep given by its votes?

Comment: I don't think there is a set value, and is handled on a case by case basis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no set reputation value.

Instead, wether or not to remove the user's votes is decided upon a case-by-case basis by the community moderators. It is quite rare that this happens at all.